# YouTube Subscriber Count

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Is there a "live subscriber count" API that is not abbreviated nowadays? If so, how can I access it?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w4F7qjmXGOE
This shows that it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't exist. The sub counts are abbreviated on youtube's end, so before it gets to the site it is already abbreviated. 
Look here: https://support.google.com/youtube/thread/6543166?hl=en. It's not like the sub counters abbreviate it. Also, the video is unavaliable